# Changing image source with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Using Jquery, I've managed to make a dropdown login form triggered by clicking a button. However, I am also trying to change the direction of the arrow next to it by replacing the src image, and it appears to do nothing.

```
$("#login_panel").slideToggle(200).toggle(
    function() { $("#arrow").attr('src', '/src/east.gif';) },
    function() { $("#arrow").attr('src', '/src/south.gif';) }
);
```

This can be seen at:
http://dev.mcmodcenter.net (The 'Login' button)

---

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$("#login_panel").slideToggle(200).toggle(
    function() { $("#arrow").attr('src', '/src/east.gif';) },
    function() { $("#arrow").attr('src', '/src/south.gif';) }
);

    for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        $(".mod").clone().insertAfter(".mod");
    }

    $(".mod").lazyload({
        effect: "fadeIn"
    });

});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can directly access `this.src` - no need to create a new jQuery object for that:

```
$('#arrow').toggle(
    function() { this.src = '/src/south.gif'; },
    function() { this.src = '/src/east.gif'; }
);
```

And if you prefer to do it via `.attr()` at least use `$(this)` (DRY - don't repeat yourself - in this case, don't specify the selector more often than necessary)

Comment: ...Apparently I was not actually editing the source. Whoops! It works now, thanks for the help.

Comment: TheifMaster had a couple important points: 1) don't do $(this) more often than once.. if anything, set a variable right off the bat to equal $(this) and then always refer to that variable (it cuts down on processing time, which will make a difference as code builds up). The other good point he/she makes is that if there is already an easy way to access an element's property through standard Javascript/DOM, do it that way because it eliminates a lot of the overhead associated with jQuery calls. *thumbs up to TheifMaster for spreading the importance of optimization!*

Comment: And thumbs down for not writing my nickname correctly twice :P

Answer (score 1):

```
    $("#arrow").toggle(
        function(){$("#arrow").attr("src", "/src/south.gif");},
        function(){$("#arrow").attr("src", "/src/east.gif");}
    );
```

You left off the "#" in the handler functions. By just referring to "arrow", you were telling jQuery to look for (presumably absent) `<arrow>` tags.

Now, as to the larger situation, what you're setting up there is something that'll make the image change when the image itself is clicked.  Your description of your goal makes me think that that's not quite what you want, but it's hard to tell.  If you want some *other* element to control the changes to the image, then you'd attach the handler(s) elsewhere.

Is the image you want to change that little black arrow next to the login button?  If so, then what should happen is that the code to set the image should be added to the existing handler that slides the login form up and down.  (By the way, in Chrome the login box shows up in what seems like an odd place, far to the left of the button.)

Comment: Good eye, but I've fixed it and it still doesn't work. Is the rest of my syntax correct?

Comment: Yeah, I've had a problem with positioning. I'm not actually sure how to keep it in one spot with a liquid layout. I've tried that as well, and I am still doing it wrong somehow :(

Comment: I wasn't actually editing the source! Thanks for the help, this works.

Answer (score 0):

`$("arrow")` will match `<arrow>`, you lost the `#`

<del>Also, the [toggle method](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) does not take two functions as its arguments, it works in a completely different way to what you are trying to do with it.</del> Yes, it does, there are two different [toggle methods](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/) for jQuery (insert rant about awful API design)

And now you have completely edited the code…

Your code now immediately assigns strings to the `this.src` (where `this` is (I think) the `document` object), and then passes those two strings as arguments to the toggle method (which are not acceptable arguments for it)

And now you have completely edited it again…

Comment: Good to know, I can use that for custom tags then.

Comment: Don't use custom tags in HTML documents.

Comment: Noted. The w3c validator would throw a fit, now that I think about it.

Answer (score 0):

looks like you forget to put the # before the arrow in $("arrow")

it should be like this

```
 $("#arrow").toggle(
            function(){$("#arrow").attr("src", "/src/south.gif");},
            function(){$("#arrow").attr("src", "/src/east.gif");}
        );
```

Comment: I've decided to follow the 'this.src' syntax of another answer, this does not work.

Comment: did you give the id = "arraow" to the <img> tag

Comment: Yes, before it is clicked it looks like this: <img id="arrow" src="/src/east.gif"/>

Answer (score 0):

This code should work:

```
$('#login_button').click(function() {
    $(this).find('#arrow').attr('src', function(i, v) {
        return v.indexOf('east.gif') < 0 ? '/src/east.gif' : '/src/south.gif';
    });

    $('#login_panel').slideToggle(200);
});
```